# Problem with flash security on offline CD presentation

Tags: security, flash, offline, sandbox

my problem touches some other questions already asked here, but no topic here has an answer, that solves this situation.

I have created web version of a certaion document, some pages in this document include **embedded flash swf files**.

The key problem is, this document is suppossed to be **distributed on CD**, so I created an offline version without problem. But after running the site offline, I come to **conflict with Flash Player security**, which asks if I really want to run the swf file ... and than crashes the Flash Player.

I know you can set up the configuration for this easily for Flash Player, you can also create a config file, that will allow you to run flash files localy. I can do those without problem.

BUT :-) ... if this CD is distributed to other people, **they won't make those changes** or steps and run into problem with flash... and yes, it's sad, but the flash has to be there :-|

Can anyone please help this problem? Because I'm running out of ideas light speed...

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1):

try setting the "local playback security" to "access local files only" if you're working in the Flash IDE. if you're compiling your SWF using the flex compiler you need to add the following flag:

```
-use-network=false
```

helpful article:
http://www.senocular.com/pub/adobe/Flash%20Player%20Security%20Basics.html

cheers